# Discord Oauth2 Token Method return invalids redirect_uri

Tags: javascript, oauth, discord

I am currently working on a project and am having an issue with trying to get a token from discords oauth2 route. Whenever I try to call my api method the discord API is responding saying that the **redirect_uri** is invalid. I am not entirely sure what I am doing wrong.

```
  let data = {
    client_id: client_id,
    client_secret: client_secret,
    code: code.toString(),
    grant_type: 'authorization_code',
    scope: 'identify',
    redirect_uri: redirect_uri,
  }
  const config = {
    headers: {'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
  }
  await Axios.post('https://discord.com/api/oauth2/token', new URLSearchParams(data), config)
    .then((res) => {
      let data = res.data;
      response.send(data);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
      response.sendStatus(500);
    })
}
```

Here is the error that I am seeing in the console:

```
data: {
  error: 'invalid_request',
  error_description: 'Invalid "redirect_uri" in request.'
}
```

Comment: Are  you sure your redirect URI scheme is matching i.e. http vs https. ?

Comment: When you created the oauth2 client in your project, you had to specify a redirect_uri. What you specified in discord has to *exactly* match what you are passing. Scheme, path, domain, port, everything has to be identical. If you got this error it means there was a mismatch.

Comment: The reason I got this error is because the I mistyped the `redirect_uri` parameter, naming it incorrectly as `redirect_url`.

Answer (score 0):

I just solved this problem for myself. It turns out, the uri must match the uri that you're using on the Discord Application Oauth2 page.

Best wishes,
Calculamatrise

Comment: This is not really a correct answer. It's not that the url must end in a slash, it must match _exactly_ what was setup. This could also mean you need to remove a slash. The redirect_uri check is an *exact match*

Comment: I realized that as I went on.

Comment: To clarify this answer more explicitly - the authentication redirect_uri needs to be THE SAME as the token redirect_uri

Comment: The answer by @wongz is correct. I used two redirect uri's and it gave me this error. The redirect_uri the code was generated should match the token redirect_uri and also, it should be added in Discord Oauth2 page