# Invalid redirect_uri in request Discord Oauth2

Tags: javascript, oauth-2.0, oauth, discord

I looked at other problems like mine, for example [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66926061/discord-oauth2-token-method-return-invalids-redirect-uri) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60093082/issue-with-discord-oauth2-redirect-uri-component). But the problems are because the URIs used aren't in the Redirect URIs in Discord OAuth2 config, and I checked them several times.

I have the following code:

```js
import querySring from 'query-string'

// I'm using React Router for this
const code = searchParams.get('code')

if (!code) return

const data = {
      'client_id': 'my client id',
      'client_secret': 'my client secret',
      'grant_type': 'authorization_code',
      'code': code,
      'redirect_uri': querySring.stringifyUrl({ url: 'http://localhost:3000/login/callback' }),
}

const strData = querySring.stringify(data)   

const headers = {
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
}

fetch('https://discord.com/api/oauth2/token', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers,
      body: strData,
})
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(console.log)
```

And I get the following error:

```js
error: "invalid_request",
error_description: "Invalid \"redirect_uri\" in request."
```

Of course, I made sure of having this redirect uri in the Discord Developer Portal:
[image: Redirect urls config]

I also tried using:

```js
const data = {
    // ...
    'redirect_uri': 'http://localhost:3000/login/callback'
}
```

But nothing, I can't find what is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As space told me in the [Discord API Server](https://discord.gg/discord-api), if I'm handling the login from the frontend I should use `response_type=token` instead of `response_type=code`

So then I can:

```js
const token = searchParams.get('access_token')
const tokenType = searchParams.get('token_type')

/// For some reason the returned url is giving # instead of ? for query
if (window.location.toString().split('#').length > 1) {
    window.location.replace(window.location.toString().replace('#', '?'))
}
        
if (!token || !tokenType) return console.log(`There is no token`)

const headers = {
    authorization: `${tokenType} ${token}`
}
```

And use these headers for fetching data:

```js
fetch('https://discord.com/api/users/@me', {
    headers,
})
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(user=> {
        // ...
     })
```